# BLE MI Band 2 Parse Activity Data

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, xiaomi

I am not really sure about the getting the history or the past activity data from Mi Band 2 device but here is what I have done (after authentication succeed):

1. send '\x01\x01\xe2\x07\x05\x03\x11\x2f\x00\x08' to
   0004 characteristic which the first
   two bytes 'x01\x01' are the command for ACTIVITY_DATA and the rest are the date time.
2. start notification on 0004 and 0005
3. send '\x02' to 0004 which is COMMAND_FETCH_DATA

and below is the part of the log that came from the notification:

```
[Log] 39500C00FF500D00FF500D00FF501100FF
[Log] 3A501100FF600E00FF600D00FF500600FF
[Log] 3B500700FF5A1400FF5A1400FF5A1400FF
[Log] 3C5A1400FF501300FF5A1400FF501200FF
[Log] 3D500C00FF500600FF501000FF500C00FF
[Log] 3E501200FF501600FF500800FF501500FF
[Log] 3F500A00FF500900FF5A1400FF501200FF
[Log] 02501700FF501700FF
[Log] 100201
```

I've read in [here](https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band/blob/94e6feaa28a392c49becc32806be8a5765316d93/MiBand/app/src/main/java/com/betomaluje/miband/bluetooth/BTCommandManager.java#L249) and [here](https://github.com/betomaluje/Mi-Band/blob/6542e34ec5f5b2190262558898ab72810f1b880f/MiBand/app/src/main/java/com/betomaluje/miband/bluetooth/BTCommandManager.java#L249) that the number of bytes is 11 but what I received was 17 bytes.

My questions are

1. Am I doing it right in sending right command to the right characteristics?
2. If yes, how to read the data? If no, what is the notified data actually for and what are the commands to send to which characteristics?

UPDATE:

I added the last two data received from the notification. I received "100201" but does this indicates that the request was a success?